# Missing main module in Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to migrate my android app from eclipse to Android studio. (0.5.4)
The project has several dependencies. (Sherlock etc)
I exported the app to Gradle and imported it in Android studio and managed to get the project to build successfully.

It appears however that only the dependencies are built.
Adding erronous lines in the app code does not trigger compile errors.

When I view project | packages, the package for my app does not show, Only the external libraries are shown.

My root level build.gradle only contains repositories and dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'
    }
```

I tried manually adding an android section with the intent to make gradle look at the source files but I had problems adding the section:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"
    }
```

As i now get the following error

> Could not find method android() for arguments xxx on root project 'zzz'.

If proceeded to add

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

Just before the android section, but now I get

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'zzz'.
>   Plugin with id 'android' not found.

Can anyone shed some light as to why i cannot have an Android section at the root level.
If the problem lies somewhere else any help would also be much appreciated.

In case it is needed, here is my settings.gradle

```
include ':external:PullToRefresh:SmoothProgressBarLib'
include ':external:ActionBarSherlock'
include ':'
include ':external:pulltorefresh-abs'
include ':external:MyAwesomeLibrary'
include ':external:PullToRefresh:pulltorefresh'
include ':external:SherlockNavigationDrawer'
include ':external:sdk:MyAwesomeSDK'
```

Answer (score 5):

You've included an `android` block inside a `buildscript` block in your top-level build file, but this is incorrect. Instead it should be structured like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"
}

dependencies {
    //Your app dependencies go here
}
```

All this is assuming that you truly have an Android application module at your project root (meaning that at your project root directory there's a **src** directory that has Android sources in it). It seems to be that you're trying to set it up this way because you also have this in your settings.gradle file:

```
include ':'
```

If that's the case, then rearranging your top-level build file as indicated above should fix it.

If you don't have a module at the project root, then you should restore the top-level build file to its original condition (take out `apply plugin` and `android`), take out that `include ':'` line from **settings.gradle**, and add an `include` statement that points to your application module.

Comment: Excellent, put the android section in the appropriate place, added a sourceSets section and it all worked.

Comment: Thanks man. in my case settings.gradle disappeared after a merge. putting it back and syncing solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your *settings.gradle* file, I don't see where you included your main module. You should add:

```
include ':mainmodule-directory'
```

Your project should, ideally, have two *build.gradle* files. One at the root level, one at the module level. In your main module, you specify that the module is an Android module by adding `apply plugin: android` in the module's *build.gradle* file. Then you specify that the entire project would need the Android plugin by using the following in the root *build.gradle* file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll glom on to this answer instead of adding my own answer. You put an `android` block inside the `buildscript` block; this is incorrect; `android` should be at the top level. You should only include this and the `apply plugin` statement if there truly is a module at the root level of your project (e.g. there is a src folder there). The fact that you have `include ':'` in your settings.gradle seems to indicate that you have a module there, provided it's correctly set up.

Comment: @ScottBarta, you might also want to include that as an independent answer because that's valuable information that explains why the OP's method of putting `android` inside `buildscript` didn't work.

Comment: Okay, done. I didn't want to steal your thunder when you were working on a legitimate answer to the question ;)