# Couldnt find target sdk with hash string 21 and also some classes are automatically omitted error

Tags: android, sdk

When I open one of my project then I find these problems of which I have taken some screenshot. Hope you can help me in solving it
 [image]

[image]

and also when I open another project then the main activity was whole empty
[image]

And this is my sdk manager where I installed the required packages
[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: one of my build.gradle is missing the other one i have mentioned above in the screenshot

Comment: Okay ,Create a new project (For testing case) .same problem ?

Comment: nope it is all okay in new project

Answer (score 2):

The error is because API 21 is not installed.
Seems that you have to either install API 21 or change the **compileSdkVersion to 23 and targetSdkVersion to 23** in the `build.gradle`(If you are using Android Studio), else check the same in **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file(Eclipse).

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my build.gradle(Module:app) is missing. what shall i do?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? If you are using Eclipse, then check your AndroidManifest.xml file and change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23.

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: I think this link can solve your problem :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115478/missing-main-module-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

### Couldnt find target sdk with hash string 21

**An integer value that represents the version of the targetSdkVersion**

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets

**Update your SDK Manager**

Improve your `build.grale` .

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' 


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync** .Hope this helps .